# Why do southern evangelical Christians in American churches say "how that" instead of how?

Tags: american-english, african-american-vernacular-english, southern-white-vernacular-english

Why do evangelical Christians in American churches say "how that" instead of how?

Ex. 1:

> Let me tell you a story about Billy Beaumont and ***how that***, for our sakes, he joined the war to fight the commies for our freedom.

Ex. 2:

> Joey: Pa, why have our pecan trees lost all their leaves?
>
> Pa: Well son, you know ***how that*** the woodpeckers will peck all kinds of holes in the trees?
>
> Joey: Yep.
>
> Pa: Well that kills the trees and that's why they ain't got leaves no more.

In my understanding, correct usage of "how that" would be:

> Well Joey, I'll you ***how that*** happened: woodpeckers killed the trees by putting all kinds of holes in 'em!

I had not heard the former usage in the two examples until I moved from Portland, OR to Alabama. Now I hear it everywhere, especially in the churches, but also just in casual conversation. I was just wanting to understand ***where that usage originated, what the reason for it is, and how widespread it is.***

Comment: Can you please make a usage example  with “how that”?

Comment: Sure ... I'll edit with examples shortly.

Comment: @user66974 Examples have been added

Comment: @BillJ Examples have been added

Comment: It's possibly a (larger) relict from something like " ... you know how it is that the woodpeckers will peck all kinds of holes ...".

Comment: But how is it peculiar to Evangelicals?

Comment: This is the _that_ that introduces tensed subordinate clauses. It's become a relative pronoun in relative clauses (_the man that they saw_), a complementizer with complement clauses (_I know that they didn't invite her_), and it **used** to be a complementizer with adverbial clauses, too, as Chaucer used it, and as still occurs in some dialects: _We ought to get a bite to eat before that we raised the tent_ occurs in an Andy Griffith routine ("What it was, was football") in his authentic North Carolina accent. It's considered nonstandard today in adverbial clauses.

Comment: The *how that* introduces a phrase that functions as a noun, as in your second example. Pa: Well son, you know (noun), right? That's a different construction than the first sentence, where the *that* isn't strictly necessary. Also, I don't hear this as being particular to evangelicals.

Comment: @Conrado I'm not sure that it is particular/peculiar to evangelicals, only that that's pretty much mostly where I've heard it.

Comment: @JohnLawler It sounds like you are on the right track. Can you create an answer with more examples of the linguistic Chaucer usage?